# changing a Qtablewidget rows based on the changes made to another QTablewidget rows

Tags: c++, qt, onchange, indexof, qtablewidget

In my Qt c++ application I have 2 single column table widgets! Each table widget has 10 rows and one table widget has userIDs from 0 to 9 and the other table widget has corresponding user names for each userID.

following is my code

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QStringList Headers1;
    QStringList Headers2;

    QStringList t1List1;

    QStringList t2List1;


    QStringList t1List1amend;


    QStringList t2List1amend;
    QStringList t2List2amend;

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();
    void getChangedIndices();




    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(10);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);

    ui->tableWidget_2->setRowCount(10);
    ui->tableWidget_2->setColumnCount(1);

    ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(0,150);
    ui->tableWidget_2->setColumnWidth(0,150);


    Headers1<<"UserID";
    Headers2<<"UserName";
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(Headers1);
    ui->tableWidget_2->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(Headers2);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    t1List1<<"0"<<"1"<<"2"<<"3"<<"4"<<"5"<<"6"<<"7"<<"8"<<"9";
    t2List1<<"John"<<"Smith"<<"Anne"<<"Kamal"<<"Yohan"<<"Aruna"<<"Yusuf"<<"ABC"<<"Shamal"<<"Lasith";

    for(int i=0;i<t1List1.size();i++){
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0,new QTableWidgetItem(t1List1[i]));
    }


    for(int i=0;i<t2List1.size();i++){
        ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(i,0,new QTableWidgetItem(t2List1[i]));
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    for(int i=0;i<t1List1.size();i++){
        t1List1amend<<ui->tableWidget->item(i,0)->text();
    }


}


void MainWindow::getChangedIndices(){
    for(int i=0;i<t1List1amend.size();i++){
        if(t1List1amend[i]!=t1List1[i]){


            t2List1.replace(i,t2List1[t1List1amend[i].toInt()]);
            t2List1amend<<t2List1[i];

        }
        else{
            t2List1amend<<t2List1[i];
        }
    }

}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
   getChangedIndices();
}
```

when push button 3 is clicked the two table widgets are displayed with userIDs and USernames. 
After changing the user IDs( eg- USerID 1 replaced with 4 and userID 4 replaced with one) push button 4 is clicked so that a QStringList with changed userIDs are created.

the getChangedIDs is used to rearrange the userNames so that the change of userIDs are depicted.(eg- previously I changed user ID 1 to 4 and userID 4 to 1).

so after clicking push button 5 userName corresponding to userID 1("Smith") should be replaced by "Yohan" and Yohan should be replaced by "Smith". currently Smith is replaced by Yohan but Yohan does not change!( 2 Yohan's are there in the final tablewidget without any smith)

How can I correct my code?

Comment: If your QTableWidget is single column why do not you use QListWidget?

Comment: @eyllanesc In my final app it may be 2 columns but if I get it done for a single column I can get it easily done for 2 columns or any number of columns :D

Comment: How do you change the userID? What happens if a new ID is created in the change?

Comment: Yes, that's because you don't keep a copy of the old value (in your case "Smith"). instead use `t2List1.swap(i,t1List1amend[i].toInt())`

Comment: @organicoman The same thing happens when I use t2List1.swap(i,t1List1amend[i].toInt()) (smith does not appear)

Comment: @KushanPeiris if you intend to see the result on screen you need to commit the list to the QtableWidget again, what you did in your code is only change the internal QStringList objects, nothing will be reflected in the screen until you tell Qt to do so. Put a break point on `t2List1.swap(i,t1List1amend[i].toInt())` and step into to follow the change.